# Problemas con diferentes caracteres Tildes, Acentos

Tags: html, utf-8, caracteres

Que tal amigos estoy batallando con el siguiente problema voy a emigrar de un dominio a otro ejemplo: www.dominio.com **al** www.dominio.com.mx y en el **.com** si me detecta bien las tildes y los acentos pero en el *.com.mx** no

Ya copie todo el proyecto y ni asi, se tendra que configurar algo en el **Cpanel** o en algun otro lado? ya que creo que el codigo no tiene nada que ver

Este es el **.com** el cual si me muestra las tildes y acentos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el **.com.mx** el cual no me muestra las tildes y acentos y pase igual el proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has comprobado la configuracion del cotejamiento en la base de datos sea la misma?

Comment: Tambien pase la base de datos (la exporte e importe) o a que te refieres con la configuracion del cotejamiento?

Comment: El cotejamiento es el conjunto de caracteres del servidor de base de datos o el Server connection collation. En `phpmyadmin` por ejemplo, aparece en la pantalla principal. Verifica que esté configurado en: `UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)` [como en este ejemplo](https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/)